# Full outer join on multiple fields

Tags: sql, sqlite, outer-join

I have several tables of academic journal rankings, from different sources and with different citation metrics. I want to combine them in a single table, aggregating data by journal.

For example, the first table has columns:

```
ISSN1 ISSN2 Journal_Name_1 Impact_Factor
```

and the second table has columns

```
ISSN3 ISSN4 ISSN5 Journal_Name_2 Citations
```

Journal names vary between data sources, and any journal may have 0 or more ISSN numbers. What I would like to do is creating a new table with columns

```
ISSN1 ISSN2 ISSN3 ISSN4 ISSN5 Journal_name_1 Journal_Name_2 Impact_factor Citations
```

that includes all journals listed in table 1 or table 2 by merging a row from the first table with one from the second table if the condition

```
( Journal_Name_1 = Journal_Name_2 ) OR ( at least one of ISSN1 or ISSN2 is equal to at least one of ISSN3, ISSN4, ISSN5)
```

What is the most effective way to create that result?

(The data is in CSV files at the moment, I could use sqlite/mysql/postgresql/any other DBMS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2243/5/0) for playing.

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1
left join t2 on (journal_name1 = journal_name2)
                or (issn1 in (issn3, issn4, issn5))
                or (issn2 in (issn3, issn4, issn5))
union all
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1
right join t2 on (journal_name1 = journal_name2)
                 or (issn1 in (issn3, issn4, issn5))
                 or (issn2 in (issn3, issn4, issn5));
```